# Селектор удаления класса кроме

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как написать селектор удаления всех классов кроме определенных

Comment: что именно у Вас вызывает затруднение? почему Вас не устраивает `removeClass()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var requireClasses = ['selector', 'test'];

$('.selector').removeClass(function (i, classNames) {
    // Если className не тот, что нам нужно оставить
    return classNames.split(' ').filter(function (className) {
        return requireClasses.indexOf(className) === -1;
    }).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: 1 - если нужно удалить все классы кроме определенного, то вешать обработчик лучше на данный класс или `id` элемента; 2 - Ваш код удаляет все классы https://jsfiddle.net/16kmvm3v/

Comment: а удаляется все потому, что в параметр className - приходит содержимое атрибута `class` - а не все классы по одному

Comment: да точно... ну тогда...

Comment: лучше не map, а filter - потому что тут именно фильтрация

Comment: @Pleshevskiy кроме этого в условии задачи - удалить все классы, кроме **определенных**, т.е. их может быть несколько.

Comment: `requireClasses`  - это массив - его нельзя вызывать с `()`

Comment: блин я заработался вобщем...

Answer (score 3):

Одним из вариантов решения может быть: удаление всех классов и добавление тех которые должны остаться заново

```
$('.selector').removeClass().addClass('all needed classes');
```

Comment: самый простой и верный способ)

Comment: @Alex, я боюсь если на классы анимации с transitions навешаны, то может быть не совсем ожидаемый результат:)

Comment: Я думаю подойдет в самый раз )

Comment: ну в вопросе кода нет и доп. условий тоже, поэтому к Вам претензий быть не может)

Comment: Мне помог ваш вариант, просто восхитителен!